# E-Mail Notification Based on Cell Change

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to write a code that will send out e-mail alerts based on when a cell value changes in different tabs.

For instance:

Cell AE1 on Tab 1 changes -- email to person 1
Cell AE1 on Tab 2 changes -- email to person 2
Cell AE1 on Tab 3 changes -- email to person 3

I've used this before and it has worked, but I do not know how to alter so that the threshold is any time the cell changes, instead of being less than/greater than a value.

```
function CheckRins() {
  // CheckRins
  var monthSalesRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary").getRange("D2"); 
  var monthSales = monthSalesRange.getValue();

  if (monthSales < 2){

    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("B2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Anthony Madle has ' + monthSales "remaining" 


+

    ; // Second column
    var subject = 'Madle Low Sales Alert';
    MailApp.sendEmail(email Address, subject, message);
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You certainly must be able to specify a sheet in the sidebar.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this not a programming question.

Comment: My apologies - I thought JavaScript could be used to solve this issue, since I cannot figure out why I am receiving duplicates using Magic Cell Notifications.

Comment: Try contacting the author of that addon.

Comment: I reached out but no response.  I'll hang tight, was just hoping maybe there was a JavaScript code to do this smoother.  No problem though, appreciate the response @Cooper

Comment: If I wanted to do it I would do it with a side bar and I would use the set interval timer to poll the locations that you setup with a high speed clock to detect changes. But the problem is that you have to leave the sidebar active all of the time.

Comment: Oh I see - that makes sense.  Thanks for your help, always much appreciated!

Comment: Hey @Cooper I updated my post so that maybe it fits guidelines better; my apologies if not -- I've used this in the past.  Any thoughts?

Comment: That's a step in the right direction now you need to set create a sidebar with the capability to run that function as often as you wish.  Or your can use a time based trigger.  But I'm not sure how fast of a trigger you can get with Google because I avoid using triggers because I don't like to waste server resources on frivolous things.  Of course, what's frivolous to me may not be frivolous to you.

Comment: Ahh I see - I had used a trigger because I've never created a sidebar before. That seems like something I'd like to learn though.

My only issue is that with this, I can only get the code to run when the cell is greater than or less than a value.  I really would like to get it so that it runs any time it changes (whether larger or smaller).  Any idea?

Comment: You can keep the last value is CacheService or PropertiesService.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple timer example:

It samples the value in A1 of Sheet13 and triggers the sendEmail() function whenever it changes.  The sendEmail function just generates an message box that says an email has be sent.  So that's where you would want to add the sendEmail function.

GS:

```
//this is what starts it all I use this name because I have a bunch of predefined menutitems for running functions
function runTwo() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('ah3'));
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet13').getRange('A1').getValue();
}

function sendEmail() {
  Browser.msgBox('Email Sent');
}

//Generate a message when the sample is stopped with the button
function stopped() {
  Browser.msgBox('Stopped');
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Stop" onClick="stop()" />
  <script>
  var timer='';
  var olddata='';
  $(function(){
    google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(function(data){
      olddata=data;
      timer=setInterval(goGetData,2000);   
    })
    .getData();    
  });

    function stop() {
      clearInterval(timer);
      google.script.run.stopped();
    }

    function goGetData() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(data){
        if(olddata!=data) {
          google.script.run.sendEmail()
          olddata=data;
        }
      })
      .getData();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Wow this is incredible. Thanks a lot!